# How to filter by duration at YouTube search API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to filter my search results by the duration (short) parameter. However, it still returns videos as long as one hour. Also, the `orderby` parameter doesn't seem to work. Here's the code (all other filters work):

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
  part: 'snippet',
  q: 'kittens',
  maxResults: 5,
  duration: 'short',
  orderby: 'published',
});
```

Does it have something to do with the fact that these are "custom search parameters"? If so, how do I use them?

Comment: Hi, any idea if there is an option to search by multiple, "short" and "medium" but not "long"?

Answer (score 3):

The search API reference says that you need to specify the "type" as video.

> If you specify a value for this parameter, you must also set the type
>   parameter's value to video.

(From: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Try adding "type" parameter to your request.